# Angular service that encapsulates Web Service data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am currently writing a frontend app with angular js.

I am using Restangular to handle all the REST request. Loading data currently works perfect.

I want to do the following:

I want to write a service/factory/provider, that returns the name of every language. This call only needs to done once in the whole workflow (it is unlikely that the languages while a user is using the application).

So I tried something like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('maroziFrontendApp')
  .service('LanguagesService', function(Restangular) {
    this.languages = Restangular.one('languages').get();
  });
```

But when I inject this in my controller (or Restangular element transformer), I will only get the promise. I then have to do another callback and that messes up the workflow.

I also tried:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('maroziFrontendApp')
  .service('LanguagesService', function(Restangular) {
    Restangular.one('languages').get().then(function(languages) {
      this.languages = languages;
    });
  });
```

But this returns `undefined` when injected.

To clarify:

I want the languages to be loaded before the controller (or elementtransformer) is hit. I cannot use `resolve` because I am not only using this service in a controller.

Is there an easy way?

Comment: Resolve is the way to do this, what does it have to do with you using this outside of a controller? Services in angular are singletons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `$object` now in Restangular since version 1.2.0

So your code would be:

```
angular.module('maroziFrontendApp')
  .service('LanguagesService', function(Restangular) {
    this.languages = Restangular.one('languages').get().$object;
  });
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.languages = LanguageService.languages
```

And in the HTML:

```
<span>{{languages.name}}</span>
```

This looks much better :)

Answer (score 1):

In your second attempt, you're referencing `this` from within the callback function and that is why I think you're getting `undefined`. The following example solves that problem.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('maroziFrontendApp')
  .service('LanguagesService', function(Restangular) {
    var self = this;
    Restangular.one('languages').get().then(function(languages) {
      self.languages = languages;
    });
  });
```

That approach is still problematic because the code that would need to make use of LanguagesService would need some way of knowing when it is available.

You might want to consider displaying some sort of "Loading" message to the user and then loading all required data using chained promises in the `module.run()` method. When all the data is loaded, you could then redirect the user to the application entry point.

Another alternative to consider is that if the list of languages is going to be the same for all users of your application, try generating and including a javascript file like the following example and you won't need to worry about async problems.

```
angular.module("maroziFrontendApp")
  .value("Languages", function() {
    return {
      "en": "English",
      "fr": "French",
      "es": "Spanish"
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since AJAX calls are asynchronous there is no way to ensure the languages are loaded before the controller function is executed.

For what it's worth, Restangular promises have a property named `$object`. It gets populated with the result as soon as a response is returned.

```
this.languages = Restangular.one('languages').get().$object;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the loading of the data on another route like /loading, once the data has been loaded you can then redirect to the page where you want to be able to instantly access the data from within the service.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of an unorthodox solution, where you bootstrap your angular app manually.

You would first init your service and then bootstrap. you have to remove the ng-app directive of course

```
var module = angular.module("app",['restangular','ngMockE2E']);

module.factory('LanguagesService', function(Restangular, $q) {
    var service = {};
    service.init = function() {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        Restangular.one('languages').get().then(function(languages) {
            service.languages = languages;
            service.init = undefined;
            defered.resolve();
        });
        return defered.promise;
    }
    return service;
});

//Manual bootstrap
function bootstrap() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['app']);
    $injector.invoke(function ($rootScope, $compile, $document, LanguagesService) {
        LanguagesService.init().then(function() {
            $compile($document)($rootScope);       
        });

    });
}
bootstrap();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/VtazD/1/

The downside is of course the initial loading time and that the mustaches are shown until the app is fully loaded, but there are solutions for this, i am sure.